# function being called on a variable

Tags: javascript

sorry for my noob question, but i cant understand what is going on, i have a function that accepts a callback, and than call this function but on a variable. The strange part is that im not calling the variable, when i load the page it automatclly runs the funtion from the variable "me" can someone explain whats going on?

```
function whoAmI(name,callback) {
  if(name === 'James') {
    console.log("You are James");
  } else {
    console.log("You are not James");
  }

  callback();
}

var me = whoAmI("Joe", function() {
  console.log('Calback Finised');
});
```

Comment: You are actually calling the function. You are delegating the function and then calling it inside your whoAmI function

Comment: What is it your wanting it to do?.   Are you wanting it so it's executed when you do  `me()` ?

Comment: Functions are just (callable) objects in JavaScript, i.e. they are values like any other value. `callback` is variable that has a function as its value. `callback();` resolves the the value of `callback` (i.e. "gets" the function object) and executes it (`()`). If you'd pass a value that is not a function you'd get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var me = whoAmI("Joe", function() {
  console.log('Calback Finised');
});
```

you are calling the function and assign her to variable `me`.

You function was created here:

```
function whoAmI(name,callback) {
  if(name === 'James') {
    console.log("You are James");
  } else {
    console.log("You are not James");
  }

  callback();
}
```

And here:

```
var me = whoAmI("Joe", function() {
  console.log('Calback Finised');
});
```

it was just invoked and this function was assigned to a variable.

Comment: `whoAmI` doesn't `return` anything, so `me` will be `undefined`.